# How to show manufacturer attributes for products with link to advanced search result?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, url, product-view, advanced-search

I am showing the `manufacturer` attribute in `catalog_product_view` page on `product/view.phtml` using **Code 1** (see below). I successfully included a list of all `manufacturer` attributes from **Code 2**.

1. How to show the result of **Code 1** with `href` link as in **Code 2**, which should redirect to advanced search result and show a list of all products for that selected manufacturer?

   (OR)
2. How to restrict the results of **Code 2** as in **Code 1** (Instead of showing all results for manufacturer make it to show only one value as in Code 1)

### Code 1

```
<?php if( $_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer') ): ?>
    <p class="manufacturer">Brand:<br/><?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer')?></p>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

Example Output of Code 1:

> Nike

### Code 2

```
<?php  
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');  
     $attributes = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')  
                   ->setEntityTypeFilter($product->getResource()->getTypeId())  
                   ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_code', 'manufacturer');  
     $attribute = $attributes->getFirstItem()->setEntity($product->getResource());  
     $manufacturers = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);  
 ?>
<ul id="manufacturer_list">    
      <?php foreach ($manufacturers as $manufacturer): ?>  
      <li><a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>catalogsearch/advanced/result/?manufacturer[]=<?php echo $manufacturer['value'] ?>"><?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer')?></a></li>  
       <?php endforeach; ?>  
 </ul>
```

Example Output of Code 2:

```
<a href="http://127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/catalogsearch/advanced/result/?manufacturer[]=14">Nike</a>,<a href="http://127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/catalogsearch/advanced/result/?manufacturer[]=11">Reebok</a>,<a href="http://127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/catalogsearch/advanced/result/?manufacturer[]=18">Adidas</a>,<a href="http://127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/catalogsearch/advanced/result/?manufacturer[]=17">Etc</a>
```

> [Nike](http://127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/catalogsearch/advanced/result/?manufacturer[]=14),[Reebok](http://127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/catalogsearch/advanced/result/?manufacturer[]=11),[Adidas](http://127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/catalogsearch/advanced/result/?manufacturer[]=18),[Etc](http://127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/catalogsearch/advanced/result/?manufacturer[]=17)

**I want it like this:**

Required  Output:

```
<a href="http://127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/catalogsearch/advanced/result/?manufacturer[]=14">Nike</a>
```

> [Nike](http://127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/catalogsearch/advanced/result/?manufacturer[]=14)

Like in Amazon:

```
http://www.amazon.in/s/ref=bl_dp_s_web_976392031?ie=UTF8&node=976392031&field-brandtextbin=Nike
```

Am using 1.9.2 Rwd theme,Any help would be appreciated..!

Answer (score 2):

You were almost there. This combination of your codes should to the trick:

```
<?php if( $_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer') ): ?>
    <p class="manufacturer">
        Brand:<br/>
        <a href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('catalogsearch/advanced/result', [
            '_query' => ['manufacturer' => $_product->getData('manufacturer')]
        ]) ?>">
            <?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer')?>
        </a>
    </p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Note that I used the standard Magento way to construct URLs instead of concatenating base URL, path and query parameters as you did. The result is the same.

What's important is that `$product->getData('manufacturer')` returns the internal value that you need for the link and `$product->getAttributeText('manufacturer')` returns the localized frontend value.

Answer (score 0):

you can use http_build_query();
**Example:**

```
<?php
$data = array('foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'boom', 'cow' => 'milk', 'php' =>'hypertext processor');

echo http_build_query($data) . "\n";
?>
```

**Output :**
foo=bar&baz=boom&cow=milk&php=hypertext+processor
[see more](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)